# Stored procedure for search operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 for retrieving value based on parameters passed from the UI.

This is basically a search operation on name with `JOIN` of many tables. My issue is that when the user does not provide a middle name my procedure is unable to access that value.

```
    P.FirstName = Coalesce( @FirstName,P.FirstName) AND 
    P.MiddleName = Coalesce(@MiddleName,P.MiddleName)  AND 
    P.LastName = Coalesce( @LastName,P.LastName) AND
    (
         P.FirstName = Coalesce(@anyName,P.FirstName)  OR
   P.MiddleName = Coalesce(@anyName,P.MiddleName)  OR
   P.LastName = Coalesce(@anyName,P.LastName) 
     )
```

I can't remove middle name because I am providing filter option on all of the above columns.

Comment: [Dynamic Search conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) - I'm guessing that `MiddleName` is nullable, and you're falling into the `NULL = NULL` trap.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
CASE WHEN @FirstName IS NULL THEN CASE WHEN P.FirstName is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ELSE CASE WHEN P.FirstName = Coalesce( @FirstName,P.FirstName) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        END = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

change to this:

```
(P.MiddleName = @MiddleName or P.MiddleName is null or @MiddleName is null)
```

Here is the full example:

```
(P.FirstName = @FirstName or P.FirstName is null or @FirstName is null) AND
(P.MiddleName = @MiddleName or P.MiddleName is null or @MiddleName is null) AND      
(P.LastName = @LastName or P.LastName is null or @LastName is null) AND     
(  @AnyName is null or
   P.FirstName =  @AnyName or
   P.MiddleName = @AnyName or       
   P.LastName   = @AnyName )
```

Comment: after making like what you suggested, my filter option is not working proprly.

Answer (score 0):

```
where (MiddleName = Coalesce(@MiddleName ,MiddleName ) or MiddleName is null)
```

don't forget to do it on both locations you reference MiddleName